# How to check the status of an application for a UK work visa for an Indian?

Tags: visas, uk, indian-citizens, scams

My husband applied for a work visa in the UK after being told to contact Mr. James Bevan via mail (`british.high.commission@india.com`). All the documents required were sent via mail and a payment of Rs.18250 was also made to Mr Naba Kumar on the 25th of July.

On 27th I received a mail stating that the documents are sent for endorsement and are approved but I was not given any visa application reference number.

How do I check the status of my visa?

Comment: `payment of rs.18250 was also made to Mr naba kumar` Why was this done to a person ? `husband had applied for a work visa in UK` What do you mean ? Applied in UK and pai INR, why ?

Comment: You were scammed per the answer below.  Try to get your documents back and alert the police.  Notify your bank and expect identity theft to be attempted.

Answer (score 6):

I am afraid that this is a visa scam. 
You should contact the local authorities immediately to report that you and your husband have been the victims of fraud.

The British High Commission, according to [their own website](https://www.gov.uk/government/world/organisations/british-high-commission-new-delhi), does not deal with visa matters.  Also, the High Commissioner is *Sir* James Bevan, and he would never be the first point of contact for routine matters of any sort.

Official UK government email addresses should always end ~gov.uk, anyone who asks you to contact any other sort of address like .com should be taken as highly suspicious.  There is also some information on [common visa scams](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/frauds-tricks-and-scams/frauds-tricks-and-scams) provided by the UK government.